# Number of convex polygons in chess board

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

how many convex k-sided polygons are made of intersection points of a $m\times n$ chess board?
i tried to determine the properties of a convex k_sided polygon and i got below statement :
"in convex k_sided polygons there is no side with line equation of $y=f(x)$ that has answer with line equations of exactly two other sides"
(i tried this for five-sided polygons and it was correct)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You should add context to your question, for instance your ideas or attempts so far. Otherwise it will probably be downvoted.

Comment: thanks for advice